# Could not find the following native modules after upgrading the react-native to latest version 0.61.4

Tags: react-native

After upgrading the react-native version I am getting the following. And failed to run the build in simulator

After this, I have run react-native run-ios it shows all my packages are manually linked and you need to unlink all packages.

Also, can anyone clarify the react-native-config.js file is mandatory for this after updating to the latest react-native.

Always I open the app.Xcodeproj but the below shows I need to open app.xcworkspace. Can anyone clarify this?

```
warn The following packages use deprecated "rnpm" config that will stop working from next release:
  - react-native-fetch-blob: https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob#readme
  - react-native-orientation: https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation#readme
  - rn-fetch-blob: https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob#readme
Please notify their maintainers about it. You can find more details at https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/configuration.md#migration-guide.
error Could not find the following native modules: BugsnagReactNative, react-native-camera, react-native-cookies, react-native-fast-image, react-native-fetch-blob, RNFS, RNGestureHandler, RNImageCropPicker, react-native-image-picker, RNImageRotate, BVLinearGradient, react-native-orientation, RNShare, RNSVG, RNVectorIcons, RNViewShot, react-native-webview, rn-fetch-blob. Did you forget to run "pod install" ?
info Found Xcode workspace "Fashion.xcworkspace"
```

Comment: have you tried unlinking all and opening xcworkspace?

Comment: I have unlinked all packages but 3 packages not get unlinked. warn The following packages use deprecated "rnpm" config that will stop working from next release:
  - react-native-fetch-blob: https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob#readme
  - react-native-orientation: https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation#readme
  - rn-fetch-blob: https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob#readme
Please notify their maintainers about it. You can find more details at https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/configuration.md#migration-guide.

Comment: oh , you should remove rnpm asap then. do post if you get the answer

Comment: Shall I need to create react-native.config.js file is a mandatory one or not?

Comment: @sejn, I have update the answer, you can try it

Comment: @Lenoarod I have removed rnpm from package.json and then run npm install and react-native run-ios. Facing same issue

Comment: Also my pod file not have any third party packages. It looks empty. Shall I know the reason

Comment: did you add the react-native.config.js, I also use rn-fetch-blob. in general:1, update the react,react-native library, 2, unlink the ios library, use pod installs it.3, remove the rnpm from package.json, add eact-native.config.js

Comment: My versions are  1.  "react": "16.8.1", 2. react-native: 0.61.4,  3. unlinked the ios  library, and run pod install from the ios folder. Here all the unlinked libraries are removed from podfile after running the pod install. 3. removed rnpm and 5. added react-native.config.js. Still getting the runtime error which I have mentioned above

Comment: While unlink it shows the below message.info iOS module "react-native-fetch-blob" is not installed
info Android module "react-native-fetch-blob" is not installed

Answer (score 25):

This should fix your issue.

```
rm -rf ios/Pods && rm -rf ios/build && cd ios && pod install && cd ../

rm -rf node_modules && rm yarn.lock && yarn install
```

PS: In react-native version 0.60 and above, native modules are now auto-linked. See the docs for more: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2019/07/03/version-60#native-modules-are-now-autolinked

Comment: Did this remove all the existing packages from Podfile?

Comment: @sejn okay. What's the update? Did that help? If no, what errors do you get? Thanks

Comment: All the packages are removed from the podfile. It has no packages after rm -rf ios/Pods && rm -rf ios/build && cd ios && pod install

Comment: ould not find the following native modules: BugsnagReactNative, react-native-camera, react-native-orientation, RNShare, RNSVG, RNVectorIcons, RNViewShot, react-native-webview, rn-fetch-blob. Did you forget to run "pod install"

Comment: @sejn the code I shared has pod install though. Anyway, kindly cd into ios directory and run pod install

Answer (score 2):

firstly, when you update the react-native version, you should react-native official [document](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading). to avoid some wrong things. the details for update in the react-native update [helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/).

and for your question, since 0.60, CocoaPods are now part of React Native's iOS project. If you weren't already, be sure to open iOS platform code using the xcworkspace file from now on.

At the same time, a react-native link is now not needed in most situations anymore.  the react-native team overhauled the linking process in general. Be sure to react-native unlink any preexisting dependencies as mentioned in the docs above.for more details, you can read this [article](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2019/07/03/version-60).

for the rnpm problem, firstly you should delete it in the package.json.
then create a react-native.config.js file in project folder.

```
const ios = require('@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios');
const android = require('@react-native-community/cli-platform-android');

module.exports = {
    project: {
      ios: {},
      android: {},
    },
    // assets: ['Resources/fonts'], // stays the same
    // commands: require('./path-to-commands.js'),
  };
```

then in the rn-fetch-blob(make is as an example), you also create 
react-native.config.js and modify it according to its rnpm config

Comment: So after update to 0.60.4 need to open xcworkspace not xcodeproj. May I know this in detail

Comment: If I use xcodeproj means it works no longer I think? Shall I need to make any changes in any place for xcworkspace?

Comment: I have opened the xcworkspace. Now I am getting React/RCTBridgeModule.h' file not found

Comment: you should remove the old link library, use pod  install to auto-link library for ios.

Comment: I have removed my old libraries, also ran pod install from the ios folder.

Comment: If I run react-native run-ios I am getting error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening App.xcworkspace. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Comment: @sejn, that because some path has changed. you can see the react-native update helper find the solution. or look my this answer(https://stackoverflow.com/a/58497815/5705408)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202881/discussion-between-lenoarod-and-sejn).

Answer (score 1):

In the latest react-native stable version, you dont need to link the 3rd party libraries, just install it and it will work fine

Firstly,

> So, when you are migrating from lower version to higher stable version,
>   then what you need to do, just unlink all the libraries you have used
>   in your project as **react-native** automatically detects its
>   dependencies. and moreover remember that whenever you install such
>   libaries you don't need to run the `react-native link <library-name>`
>   to link it.

Secondly,

> Now you need to work with *xcworkspace* file as in the latest version,
>   ios are dealing with pods, and when pods comes into picture then you
>   have to use *xcworkspace* instead of *Xcodeproj* in your ios project

You can check the changelog [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.61.0) for react native 0.61.4 version.

I hope this helps....Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to **combine** some tips above and update mine Pod file

1. Simply reset:

   rm -rf ios/Pods && rm -rf ios/build

   cd ios && pod install && cd ..

   rm -rf node_modules && rm yarn.lock && yarn install

Reason is to maximize future compatibility.

2. Here is a facebook provided template, pick some goodies for your existing old pod file:

   https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0.63-stable/template/ios/Podfile

You may found code below is `auto linking`,

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
```

You may need to upgrade ios target

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
```

You may use Flipper without `use_frameworks! enabled`

Answer (score 0):

Could be that there is something in your podfile that causes this. For example, I removed a library from my project but there was still a reference to it in the podfile:

```
   pod 'react-native-onesignal', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-onesignal'
```

Once commenting/removing this line, `pod install` works great.

Answer (score 0):

For me just converting npm install to yarn install worked because other team was using yarn and i was trying to install packages using npm so it created some conflict.
I recloned the project then
'yarn install', 'react-native link' and then
'pod install'