# Clarification: Can anyone build app successfully with react-native latest (0.61.5) after upgrading to latest

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have a clarification. I am trying to upgrade my react-native version. But still, it shows the runtime errors. Can anyone able to build the react-native (0.61.5) without any issues.

React/RCTBridgeModule.h' file not found is faced by many of us. No solution yet. So I moving to 0.60.0. Anyone have any good solution.

```
In file included from /Applications/App/ios/helloworld/AppDelegate.m:11:
../node_modules/bugsnag-react-native/cocoa/BugsnagReactNative.h:3:9: fatal error: 'React/RCTBridgeModule.h' file not found
```

Note: pod install from ios folder, cleaning the pod and Xcode and also I tried with many solutions. Nothing worked for me.

> My Podfile Before

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
#platform :ios, '9.0'
#require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'

target 'App' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
   use_frameworks!

  # Pods for App

  target 'App-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
    pod 'rn-fetch-blob', :path => '../node_modules/rn-fetch-blob'
    #pod 'BugsnagReactNative', :path => '../node_modules/bugsnag-react-native'
    #pod 'rn-fetch-blob', :path => '../node_modules/rn-fetch-blob'

    pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'
    pod 'RNImageCropPicker', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-image-crop-picker'

    pod 'react-native-camera', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-camera'

    pod 'RNImageRotate', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-image-rotate'

    pod 'RNShare', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-share'

    pod 'RNViewShot', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-view-shot'

    pod 'RNFS', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fs'

    pod 'BugsnagReactNative', :path => '../node_modules/bugsnag-react-native'

  end

  target 'AppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

> My Podfile now

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'

target 'App' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
   use_frameworks!

  # Pods for App

  target 'App-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing

  end

  target 'Apptests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Comment: you can see this answer(https://stackoverflow.com/a/58988367/5705408), the question  is the same with this

Comment: But nothing helped for me. I am facing same issue for more than two days. So I need to confirm can anyone build the app without any issues. (While upgrade). Kindly refer this thread commenthttps://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25838#issuecomment-558749126

Comment: I update react-native to 0.61.2, it works well.

Comment: Is it autolink or manual link

Comment: I use pod install

Comment: So you using auto linking only

Comment: yes, after update react-native, I don't use the manual link. I solve the problem based on it. the pod has many problems from ios in react native. but be patient. every thing has a solution

Comment: @Lenoarod Can you confirm after upgrading how your Header Seach Paths are. Is it like (${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/BugsnagReactNative") this? Or ($RCTROOT/filename)